# IF statement with Graph API

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to show from data from Graph API, however I'm new with PHP and I'm struggling to get it to work. I've been working with the old API and have only just managed to convert some old code to new code, so it's a little messy. Can anyone see what's stopping this from functioning?

```
echo  print_r( $graphObject, 1 );
        echo "<br><h2><b><u>First Company</u></b></h2>";
          echo 'Name: '.$graphObject->getProperty('name').;
          echo 'Phone: '

          if .$graphObject->getProperty['phone']. {
              echo .$graphObject->getProperty('phone');
          } else {
              echo "No phone number available.";
          }
```

I've managed to get the 'Name', but I'm trying to create an IF statement as the page doesn't have a phone number available.

Comment: `if` uses brackets: `if (some value)`

Comment: (1). Do not do echo print_r(), this will o/p 1
(2). Line number 3, dot before semi colon
(3). Line number 4, no semicolon
(4). if condition syntax wrong.
(5). Unnecessary dot on line 7

(6). [PHP Docs](http://php.net/docs.php)

(7). Read number 6.

Comment: your code quality is very poor, full of syntax errors, you need to read the manual

Comment: I understand my coding is poor, that's why I've come here to ask people who do know, so I can learn. Can anyone give me pointers as to why I'm receiving minus marks against my questions? Am I doing something wrong when asking a question about something I'm learning about?

Comment: @symbolicConstant Thank you for the comments, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
if .$graphObject->getProperty['phone'].
```

with

```
if (isset($graphObject->getProperty['phone']))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
print_r($graphObject);
echo "<br><h2><b><u>First Company</u></b></h2>";


echo 'Name: ';

if (!empty($graphObject->getProperty('name'))) {
    echo $graphObject->getProperty('name');
} else {
    echo "No name available.";
}

echo 'Phone: ';

if (!empty($graphObject->getProperty('phone'))) {
    echo $graphObject->getProperty('phone');
} else {
    echo "No phone number available.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm receiving an 'Can't use method return value in write context' error when I try this. What does this signify?

Comment: See the updated code. I changed `isset` to `!empty`. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks again, but still the same error message, except I don't get two errors messages this time, only one. Before I got the same error message about 2 seconds apart. Could you also explain to me what this error message actually means?

Comment: My bad - check it now. I put in `!empty` for the name also. I've never seen that error before, not really sure what its meaning is. However, I'm pretty sure the error is occuring when you are trying to print the return value of `getProperty`, but whatever `getProperty` is returning can't be printed as a string.

Comment: I appreciate the help buddy, but got the same error. I'll investigate other methods of taking the data from it. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Hard to debug with you since I've never used the object. Good luck though!